# GCM 3.0 - gcm doesn't automatically show notification with notification parameter

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

The new GCM 3.0 should allow GCM to automatically display notifications sent from server if they contain the `notification` parameter.

As said in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#payload):

> The notification parameter with predefined options indicates that GCM will display the message on the client app’s behalf if the client app implements GCMListenerService on Android

However I have trouble getting that to work even though the `GCMListenerService` is implemented.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="cz.kubaspatny.pushservertest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="cz.kubaspatny.pushservertest.gcm.CustomGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**CustomGcmListenerService.java**

```
public class CustomGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle extras) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, extras);
        Log.d("GcmListenerService", "Received gcm from " + from + " with bundle " + extras.toString());
    }
}
```

The notification from server is logged but not shown by GCM.

```
Received gcm from 333813590000 with bundle Bundle[{notification={"icon":"ic_launcher.png","body":"great match!","title":"Portugal vs. Denmark"}, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

The message sent from server:

```
{       
      "registration_ids":[...],
      "data": {
        "notification" : {
            "body" : "great match!",
            "icon" : "ic_launcher.png",
            "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
          }
      } 
}
```

---

Is there anything else needed to be done to allow the automatic display?

Comment: What are you sending in `notification` payload?

Comment: @shkschneider edited the question. But i am sending `title`, `body` and `icon`

Comment: what do you mean by "automatic display"?

Comment: @injecteer at the I/O 15 it was said that GCM will display a notification by itself if it contains certain information (title, icon, text). Or as said in the docs `GCM will display the message on the client app’s behalf if the client app implements GCMListenerService`

Comment: maybe in the upcoming sdk release?

Comment: @injecteer I don't think so, it should have been part of Google Play Services 7.5. See the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/a-closer-look-at-google-play-services-75.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the notification field a sibling of the data field. The data field is passed to onMessageReceived and the notification field is used to automatically generate the notification.

```
{       
      "registration_ids":[...],
      "notification" : {
            "body" : "great match!",
            "icon" : "ic_launcher.png",
            "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
      }

}
```